# How to align message in dialog function and reuse the function?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to create a function for dialog method and reuse the function later on.

Code to create a dialog within a function:

```
private void alertView( String message ) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    dialog.setTitle( "Hello" )
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i){
                }
            }).show();
}
```

Code to call this function:

```
alertView("My message");
```

This works fine but I want to center my message. I have looked for solutions and used various methods such as:

```
    AlertDialog alert = dialog.show();
    TextView messageText =(TextView)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    messageText.setTextColor(Color.RED)
```

Nothing works. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html Scroll down to "creating a custom layout".

Comment: As far as I know, `Alerts` will be left-oriented, whereas `Simple dialogs` will  be centrally-oriented.
Please check [this](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-simple-menus) Material Design document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my question from this website: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/dialog/android-custom-dialog-example/

Created an xml layout as described on the website and made a little change to the code in my java class:

```
private void alertView( String message ) {
    //create a dialog component
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    //tell the dialog to use the dialog.xml as its layout description
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("your title");

    TextView txt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setText(message);
    Button dialogButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButton);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mUartCom.write("D"); //change this 
        }
    });

    dialog.show();

}
```

and then I've reused this function numerous times by changing the message:

```
alertView("Please select one of the red icons to begin");
```